# How to properly login to reddit via python requests?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, csrf, reddit

I am trying to login to my reddit account using `python`, not `Praw`. I succufully extracted the `CSRF token`, but still don't know why it is not functional and unable to properly login. The desired behavior of the code is  to be able to login to reddit through this python script and then confirm if the logging was a success or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to login on your browser, in the developer tools (Network tab) you can preview how the request should look. The mistake you made here is that the POST request should be sent not to: https://www.reddit.com/, but https://www.reddit.com/login.

To verify the result you can check, in the debugger, the response you received to your POST request. When I ran your code with the mentioned change of URL the response to "r" was: [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i295x.png)

You can see that the server returned response status code 400 with explanation "incorrect username or password". It means that your code should be enough to login to Reddit with inputting the correct credentials.